# React-Native) How to retrieve object values ​in an array | Minified React error #301

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
export default function App() {
  const [arrays, setArrays] = useState([]);
  const initArray = [
    { id: 2023, solveTF: false, rightTF: false },
    { id: 2025, solveTF: false, rightTF: false },
  ];
  setArrays(initArray);
  
  const idArrays = [2022,2023,2025,2027];
  const idSearch = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < idArrays.length; i++) {
      let idArray = idArrays[i]
      let newArray = arrays.filter((item) => item.id == idArray).map();
      console.log(newArray);
    }};

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => idSearch()}>
        <Card>
          <AssetExample />
        </Card>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I want to check if a value in idArrays exists in arrays.
If not, I want to add a new object to the arrays.
What did I do wrong and what should I do?

I worked with snack.expo.dev.
[Minified React error #301] is occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the state inside the `useState` to avoid an unwanted rerender.

For what you want is better to use `some` inside of `filter` to check the ids that aren't in `arrays` and then use `setArrays` to add a new object for each id not already in.

```
export default function App() {
    // Initialize inside useState
    const [arrays, setArrays] = useState([
        { id: 2023, solveTF: false, rightTF: false },
        { id: 2025, solveTF: false, rightTF: false },
    ]);

    const idArrays = [2022, 2023, 2025, 2027];
    const idSearch = () => {
        const notExistInArrays = idArrays.filter(id => !arrays.some(item => item.id === id));
        setArrays(prevArrays => [
            ...prevArrays,
            ...notExistInArrays.map(id => ({ id, solveTF: false, rightTF: false }))
        ]);
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => idSearch()}>
                <Card>
                    <AssetExample />
                </Card>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}
```